# How to use Map to search for data in a list of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary

the following code:

```
mylist = [('Wheatley','808321'),('Smith','009557'),('Stewart','808123')]

results = [last_name for (last_name,person_id) in mylist if person_id == '808123']
print(results[0])
'''Another way would be using map and filter: '''

print(set(map(lambda x: x[0], mylist)))

mine = list(zip(*mylist))
print(mine[1])
```

produces:

```
Stewart
{'Wheatley', 'Smith', 'Stewart'}
('808321', '009557', '808123')
```

How do I get the map function and zip function to search for the person_id == 808123 and only have the answer 'Stewart'?

Comment: `mydict = dict((k,v) for (v,k) in mylist)` then you have a dict which maps id's to names. (If you're using 2.7 or 3, you can instead use `mydict = {k: v for (v,k) in mylist}`)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `filter` function

```
filter(lambda x: x[1] == '808123', mylist)[0][0]
```

produces  `'Stewart'`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the`zip()`function to use the`map()`function:

```
mylist = [('Wheatley','808321'),('Smith','009557'),('Stewart','808123')]

mine = map(None, (item for item in mylist if item[1] == '808123'))

print mine[0][0]  # -> Stewart
```

However a list comprehension is the better alternative.

```
mine = [item for item in mylist if item[1] == '808123']
```